# how to burn cookies?

Tags: python, django

help please write cookies in django1.6

there is a function in views.py:

```
def custom_proc(request):
    response.set_cookie( 'cookie_user_pk', 'qwertyu' )

    return{
        'id': request.user.pk,
    }
```

it is necessary to make an entry in COOKIES

but I get the following error message:

> Exception Value:   global name 'response' is not defined

Comment: I don't use django, but what is `response` supposed to be? Should it be `request.set_cookie` or is `response` a global? In which case, `global response; response.set_cookie`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this import:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

add this line:

```
response = HttpResponse("your data to return")
```

Result:

```
def custom_proc(request):
    response = HttpResponse("your data to return")
    response.set_cookie( 'cookie_user_pk', 'qwertyu' )

    # render template / redirect (your call) 

    return response
```